# Tierprice decimals display

Tags: product, tierprice, price

I am trying to display all prices with 4 decimals (i know a little bit weird but the customer demanded this). I have overwritten Mage/Core/Store, changed the currency.php precision in the Zend lib and adjusted Mage_Directory_Model_Currency.

In the backend, all my prices are displayed correctly but in the frontend i receive a price rounded to 2 decimals followed by 00. Especially the tier price is very crucial.

Since i dont have any knowledge in pricing i have tried some tutorials on Magento Forum with no success. I also tried 2 extensions with no luck.

Any help?

Comment: 4 decimal precision is inherently imprecise in Magento.

Comment: What prices are stored in database after editing prices in backend? Maybe problem is not in frontend?

Comment: @benmarks please put this as an answer, you are completely right, I have tested it thoroughly and I'm getting 1 problem after another

Comment: I'll defer to someone with the time to really get into the specifics - afraid I'm short of time right now. Perhaps you could post this yourself along with your findings. The issue is a mix of how PHP deals with float precision and how the framework handles rounding for precision.

Comment: Yes, will try to find some time @benmarks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided not to do it and adviced the customer to refrain from pushing it because I could not get any exact results. As mentioned in the comments:

4 decimal precision is inherently imprecise in Magento.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find what you need in the `format` method inside `app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php`.

```
/**
 * Format price to currency format
 *
 * @param   double $price
 * @param   bool $includeContainer
 * @return  string
 */
public function format($price, $options=array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
{
    return $this->formatPrecision($price, 2, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
}
```

Comment: tried that didn't work :(

Comment: You set the precision from `2` to `4`? I tested this on a stock install and it changed my price displays right away. You may want to check for other modules that are overwriting this class.

Comment: been looking for classes that extend app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php in my local and community folder with no luck, didn't find some kind of observer either pretty weird :(

Comment: Also check the `design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/catalog/product/price.phtml` template to make sure it is still using the core currency helper.

Comment: @pspahn Can you please let me know how I can add a check in this function so i can display a precission on 4 digits ONLY on products that have tier pricing and not on every product? I tried by `if (Mage::registry('product')->getTierPrice())` which works on product page but I can't get something that works on category page loop. `Mage::registry('current_product')` don't.

Answer (score 0):

I had to completely rewrite my template's `price.phtml` anyway, and I used
`<?php printf("$%.2f", $_finalPrice) ?>` so you could do the same but with `%.4f`

Also, if needing to perform comparisons on floats, I recommend:
`if( abs($_price1 - $_price2) < .0001 )` instead of `if($_price1 == $_price2)`

Sometimes, php's type flexibility induces unexpected errors, so explicit casting to your desired data type is often needed: `$margin=(float)1-$margin;` I have gotten to where I don't even try to stack multiple math operations into one line of code.